# Legal site SQL injection attack

Tags: web, sql-injection, code-injection, web-testing

i have to write a report based on an a simple SQL injection attack. In this report i have to provide screenshots of my "walkthrough" so i cannot use pictures of other tutorials on the web. Now my question is: can anybody tell me the names of some websites vulnerable to SQL injection attack on which i can test my attack legally? Thanks to Google dorks i have already found some vulnerable websites, but i think that running the attack over them is illegal. I want to avoid the setting up of a personal website for this purpose, but if there are no other solutions i need an help also in setting up this kind of site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a web application called DVWA (Damn Vulnerable Web Application), it's not hosted on the internet. you have to download it and run as localhost on your computer. However it has a range of vulnerabilities, i have used it in the past for trying out a brute force attack. As its localhost its legal. it should be ideal for a walk through tutorial. I know you said that you didn't want to setup your own website, but the setup is a few minutes. Hope this Helps :D

Link: http://www.dvwa.co.uk/

Comment: I have used it. It requires some time for the configuration on kali linux but it works. Thank you!